# how two links are linked together in Java built-in libraries?

Tags: java

for example in Scanner we have 
obj.next()

but we can call another method after next()

```
obj.next().charAt(0)
```

how can I make similar thing for example

```
obj.getName().toLowerCase()
```

Comment: There isn't anything special going on here. `next` returns a string, then `charAt` is called on that string. If `getName` returns a string, your code should already work. What's the problem?

Comment: there is no problem I just want to know how to link my own methods in the same way

Comment: Again, there isn't anything special going on. The first bit of code is the same thing as `String str = obj.next(); str.charAt(0);`, just without the intermediate `str` variable. You just need to have your methods return objects instead of being `void`. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have observed – with examples like `obj.getName().toLowerCase()` – is that when the *return type* of a method call is itself some other object, then you can immediately call a new method on that newly returned object.

Here's another example: `String s = String.class.getName().toLowerCase();`. This example could be rewritten like so:

```
Class<String> stringClass = String.class;
String name = stringClass.getName();
String s = name.toLowerCase();
```

Both of the one-line and multi-line version of this code result in a String object, referenced by `s`, which contains the value "`java.lang.string`".

Note that chaining method calls together is *not* possible if the return type *isn't* an object, such as an `integer` value. For example, here's a method call that results in a primitive `long` value, which isn't an object, so you can't call any methods on that result – that is, something like `millis.hashCode()` isn't possible.

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

To address your primary question finally: you can create this same behavior by creating methods that return objects instead of primitives (int, long, byte, etc.).

Comment: I am just a beginner, does that kind of code have a name ? like abstraction or encapsulation ?

Comment: @BamoB0 "Method chaining" is a general term. Note though, chaining methods in long chains is often a sign of poor design. Unless you're using something like the builder pattern, long chains of methods can violate the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).